# AngularJS, TypeError: mapService.sayHello is not a function

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm getting a TypeError when I call a function in my service / factory.
Pretty strange, same method of setting up controllers and service are working fine in another application. But not in the application I'm trying to build now with Ionic/AngularJS.

Can any one see what I am doing wrong in the code?

Here is my controller.js

```
(function () {

angular.module('driv.MapCtrl', [])
    .controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope','mapService', MapCtrl]);

function MapCtrl($scope, mapService) {

    mapService.sayHello().success(function () {

    });           
}
})();
```

And my Service.js looks like:

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular.module('driv.mapService', [])
   .service('mapService', function () {

       //alert('Kommer til Service');

       this.sayHello = ['John', 'James', 'Jake'];

   })
})();
```

If I comment out the alert message then it fires up, so it seems like this.sayHello never invokes or fires up, and I get an error message saying mapService.sayHello is not a function. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues here:

- you define `sayHello` in your service as an array
- you are calling it as a function
- you are using result of it as a promise ( ie calling `.success` on it)

So you either need to fix the consumer , ie controller code, or fix the service, for instance

```
 (function () {
   "use strict";
   angular.module('driv.mapService', [])
     .service('mapService', function ($q) {

   this.sayHello = function() {
      return $q(function(resolve, reject) {   
        return resolve( ['John', 'James', 'Jake'] )
      })
   }
```

})

Answer (score 1):

You define `this.sayHello` as an array, and you try to execute it as a function.

```
 this.sayHello = ['John', 'James', 'Jake'];
 mapService.sayHello()
```

You either have to reformat your `this.sayHello` to a function or treat it differently in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you have your controller inside your injections:

```
(function () {

angular.module('driv.MapCtrl')
    .controller('MapCtrl', MapCtrl);

MapCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','mapService'];

function MapCtrl($scope, mapService) {

    console.log(mapService.sayHello());
}
```

You had your Service function defined as an array:

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular.module('driv.mapService')
   .service('mapService', function () {
     var arrNames = ['John', 'James', 'Jake'];    

       //alert('Kommer til Service');

       this.sayHello = function() { return arrNames; }

   })
```

You also declare the module with each call when you use:

```
angular.module('app', [])
```

Don't use the '[]' unless you are declaring the module for the first time

Comment: Oki, Thanks alot for replay.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks alot for replaying... :)

1. I have declared my module like:
   angular.module('app', [])

If i Change it to: angular.module('app'), as you say then my application stop working and gives a blank page with error messages:
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] and Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

2.
I changed my code in service.js to:

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular.module('driv.mapService')
   .service('mapService', function () {

       var arrNames = ['John', 'James', 'Jake'];

       this.sayHello = function () {
           return arrNames;
       };

   })
```

})();

And in my MapCTRL i changed it to:

```
(function () {

angular.module('driv.MapCtrl')
    .controller('MapCtrl', MapCtrl);

MapCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'mapService'];

function MapCtrl($scope, mapService) {

    mapService.sayHello().then(function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }, function (error) {
        alert('Error');
    });           
}
```

})();

Still iam getting TypeError: mapService.sayHello(...).then is not a function, what iswrong with the code her now?

Answer (score 0):

If i call my service like this:

```
 mapService.sayHello();
```

Then it works, but when i call my service like:

```
    mapService.sayHello().then(function (results) {
        alert(results);
    }, function (error) {
        alert('Error');
    });
```

ABOVE CODE Dosent work....why?